# How my native code is converted to HTML tags ? Does my browser plays important role

Tags: java, html, browser

Need to know how all source code is converted to HTML tags? Do we have any interface which will perform this action?? Also does my browsers plays important role in converting to html tags ?
Kindly clarify.

Comment: What code do you mean? Can you show it to us?

Comment: As simply as possible: HTML is a document format, that uses tags.  A Webserver's job is to return HTML.  But HTML is horrible to write by hand.  So Webservers like Tomcat allow you to write Java code to produce that HTML.  LIbraries can also be used (e.g. Spring MVC, Struts) to make that even easier. The ultimate aim of all of them is to produce lovely pure HTML.  And Browsers do nothing, other than turn those HTML tags into pretty boxes, fields and labels; and send off the *next* request to the Webserver. Which returns more HTML.  etc.  So read up on HTTP messages, HTML, and Webservers.

Comment: code like java or .net

Comment: See Mr Spoon's answer. Source code like java is never automatically converted to HTML except you specify how it is done. There are variations how to achieve this but to help you with this your question should be more precise.

Comment: @MrSpoon Thanks for your answers and it clarified my doubt :)

Answer (score 0):

The interface you are looking for is called the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) (Document Object Model).
Every major browser has his own engine with their own implementation, so differences can occur (They play an important role).